# how does the middleware work in json-server

Tags: express, middleware, json-server

As I know, in the express environment, the plumbing pipe of middleware will be executed like a stack. for example:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const router = createRouter();

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("before");
    next();
    console.log("after");
    })

function createRouter() {
    const router = express.Router()
    router.render = (req,res)=>{
        console.log("foo");
        res.send("hello, foo")
    }

    router.use((req, res) => {
        router.render(req, res);
    })
    
    return router;
}

app.use(router)

app.listen(3000)
```

this works as I expect when I access "http://locahost:3000/" and the output is:

```
before
foo
after
```

but when coming with json-server, I get confused. for example:

```
// server.js
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
const app = jsonServer.create();
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json');
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("before")
    next()
    console.log("after")
    })

router.render = (req, res) => {
  console.log("foo")
  res.send("hello, foo")
}

// Use router
app.use(router)

// Start server
app.listen(3000)
```

the output is

```
before
after
foo
```

why here "foo" comes after "after"? how this happens?